# How to enable redirect mode for Google login button?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, google-signin, flask-dance

I'm setting up a Google login option using [flask-dance](https://readthedocs.org/projects/flask-dance/downloads/pdf/stable/). My route I've create `"http://localhost/login/google"` successfully directs you to sign in with google and returns a json with information.

Now I need to enable a link for users to get there. None of the instructions in [flask-dance documentation](https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) or any user guides explain how to generate the login button. They basically just tell you to go to the login URL you create in the process. I'm certain I could just make a Google link on my page but I was trying to use the official button.

[Googles documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button#redirect_mode) explains there is a pop-up and redirect option but how to enable it isn't easy to find. I've tried putting in the `"data-login-uri"` where I want the user to login from but when I load the HTML on my localhost it defaults to a blank pop-up window.

I think I just need to enable to redirect mode they talk about in their documentation but I can't seem to figure out how.

Here is the HTML for the Google oath button I am using:

```
<!-- google oauth -->
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5 mb-4">
    <div id="g_id_onload" 
        data-client_id="..."
        data-login_uri="http://localhost/login/google" 
        data-auto_prompt="false">
    </div>
    <div class="g_id_signin" 
        data-type="standard" 
        data-logo_alignment="center"
        data-size="large" 
        data-theme="filled_blue" 
        data-shape="circle"
        data-text="continue_with"
        data-width=360>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it by using's the [HTML generator](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/tools/configurator) in Googles developer tools. I added the `data-context="signin"` and `data-ux_mode="redirect"` to the HTML and it now redirects users to the correct endpoint instead of the default pop up window.

```
<!-- google oauth -->
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5 mb-4">
    <div id="g_id_onload" 
        data-context="signin"
        data-ux_mode="redirect"
        data-client_id="<your id here>"
        data-login_uri="<your endpoint here" 
        data-auto_prompt="false">
    </div>
    <div class="g_id_signin" 
        data-type="standard" 
        data-logo_alignment="center"
        data-size="large" 
        data-theme="filled_blue" 
        data-shape="circle"
        data-text="continue_with"
        data-width=360>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
I have found that in flask_dance's current version the official google button does not play nice. With the redirect mode functioning, I encountered errors when using the login interface.
I ended up just using html/css I found where someone else had designed the google login button from scratch and just using that as a link to the endpoint flask_dance wanted.

Comment: A year later I can confirm there's still no easy way to use Flask-Dance with Google's login buttons. My solution was to add an onclick="window.location.href = '/login/google'" attribute (or however else you want to add a click listener) to the g_id_signin div pointing to my Flask-Dance blueprint. This, of course, overrides the button's purpose but at least we still get the nice official interface with the account preview! :)